# JDBC Begin transaction fails usually and recovers automatically

Tags: java, hibernate, jdbc, glassfish

I get some errors concerning the JDBC to begin transaction which fails at random times and recovers at a random time. We're using Java EE and GlassFish server to run a bank wallet-related service which should be running efficiently but unfortunately, it fails. I restart the server but it's not the once-in-a-lifetime solution that I'm seeking. I suppose that all functions are well written (The project is not mine and I don't have the code at the moment)

Here's the error:

```
[#|2022-07-27T07:49:40.068+0200|SEVERE|glassfish 4.0||_ThreadID=22;_ThreadName=T
hread-4;_TimeMillis=1658900980068;_LevelValue=1000;|
  org.hibernate.TransactionException: JDBC begins transaction failed:
        at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jdbc.JdbcTransaction.doBegi
n(JdbcTransaction.java:76)
        at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.spi.AbstractTransactionImpl.begin(Ab
stractTransactionImpl.java:162)
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.beginTransaction(SessionImpl.java:
1471)
        at com.fawryis.ebpp.NewWebServiceFromWSDL.saveTransaction(NewWebServiceF
romWSDL.java:455)
        at com.fawryis.ebpp.NewWebServiceFromWSDL.setDataReq(NewWebServiceFromWS
DL.java:436)
        at com.fawryis.ebpp.NewWebServiceFromWSDL.debitAddReq(NewWebServiceFromW
SDL.java:210)
        at com.fawryis.ebpp.NewWebServiceFromWSDL.process(NewWebServiceFromWSDL.
java:98)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor61.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAcces
sorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
        at org.glassfish.webservices.InstanceResolverImpl$1.invoke(InstanceResol
verImpl.java:143)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.server.InvokerTube$2.invoke(InvokerTube.java:149)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.server.sei.SEIInvokerTube.processRequest(SEIInvokerTub
e.java:88)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.__doRun(Fiber.java:1136)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber._doRun(Fiber.java:1050)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.doRun(Fiber.java:1019)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.runSync(Fiber.java:877)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.helper.AbstractTubeImpl.process(AbstractTubeI
mpl.java:136)
        at org.glassfish.webservices.MonitoringPipe.process(MonitoringPipe.java:
142)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.helper.PipeAdapter.processRequest(PipeAdapter
.java:119)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.__doRun(Fiber.java:1136)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber._doRun(Fiber.java:1050)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.doRun(Fiber.java:1019)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.runSync(Fiber.java:877)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.helper.AbstractTubeImpl.process(AbstractTubeI
mpl.java:136)
        at com.sun.enterprise.security.webservices.CommonServerSecurityPipe.proc
essRequest(CommonServerSecurityPipe.java:210)
        at com.sun.enterprise.security.webservices.CommonServerSecurityPipe.proc
ess(CommonServerSecurityPipe.java:142)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.helper.PipeAdapter.processRequest(PipeAdapter
.java:119)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.__doRun(Fiber.java:1136)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber._doRun(Fiber.java:1050)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.doRun(Fiber.java:1019)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.runSync(Fiber.java:877)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.server.WSEndpointImpl$2.process(WSEndpointImpl.java:42
0)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter$HttpToolkit.handle(HttpAdap
ter.java:687)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter.handle(HttpAdapter.java:266
)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.ServletAdapter.handle(ServletAd
apter.java:169)
        at org.glassfish.webservices.JAXWSServlet.doPost(JAXWSServlet.java:169)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java
:1682)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperV
alve.java:318)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextV
alve.java:160)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.j
ava:734)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.jav
a:673)
        at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.j
ava:174)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.j
ava:357)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.jav
a:260)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(Container
Mapper.java:188)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.
java:191)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.ja
va:168)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpSer
verFilter.java:189)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(Executor
Resolver.java:119)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(De
faultFilterChain.java:288)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart
(DefaultFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultF
ilterChain.java:136)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultF
ilterChain.java:114)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.jav
a:77)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNI
OTransport.java:838)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(Abstr
actIOStrategy.java:113)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerTh
readIOStrategy.java:115)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(Wo
rkerThreadIOStrategy.java:55)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadR
unnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:135)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(Abs
tractThreadPool.java:564)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(Abstra
ctThreadPool.java:544)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: Closed Connection
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.getAutoCommit(PhysicalConnectio
n.java:4337)
        at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jdbc.JdbcTransaction.doBegi
n(JdbcTransaction.java:68)
        ... 65 more|#]
```

Here is the full log:

```
[#|2022-07-27T07:49:40.006+0200|INFO|glassfish 4.0||_ThreadID=22;_ThreadName=Thr
ead-3;_TimeMillis=1658900980006;_LevelValue=800;|
  ***Start Debit Add Request *******|#]

[#|2022-07-27T07:49:40.006+0200|INFO|glassfish 4.0||_ThreadID=22;_ThreadName=Thr
ead-3;_TimeMillis=1658900980006;_LevelValue=800;|
  accountId::  Zq6FEXkQ7KzHhY9rxeNMTw==|#]

[#|2022-07-27T07:49:40.006+0200|INFO|glassfish 4.0||_ThreadID=22;_ThreadName=Thr
ead-3;_TimeMillis=1658900980006;_LevelValue=800;|
  decryptedAccNo:::  0050000015557|#]

[#|2022-07-27T07:49:40.006+0200|INFO|glassfish 4.0||_ThreadID=22;_ThreadName=Thr
ead-3;_TimeMillis=1658900980006;_LevelValue=800;|
  transactionAmt:::  50.0|#]

[#|2022-07-27T07:49:40.006+0200|INFO|glassfish 4.0||_ThreadID=22;_ThreadName=Thr
ead-3;_TimeMillis=1658900980006;_LevelValue=800;|
  *********Starting check account amount Validation*******|#]

[#|2022-07-27T07:49:40.006+0200|INFO|glassfish 4.0||_ThreadID=22;_ThreadName=Thr
ead-3;_TimeMillis=1658900980006;_LevelValue=800;|
  accountNo:::  0050000015557|#]

[#|2022-07-27T07:49:40.006+0200|INFO|glassfish 4.0||_ThreadID=22;_ThreadName=Thr
ead-3;_TimeMillis=1658900980006;_LevelValue=800;|
  amount:::  50.0|#]

[#|2022-07-27T07:49:40.068+0200|INFO|glassfish 4.0||_ThreadID=22;_ThreadName=Thr
ead-3;_TimeMillis=1658900980068;_LevelValue=800;|
  amount in account>>>:::  185675.54**true|#]

[#|2022-07-27T07:49:40.068+0200|INFO|glassfish 4.0||_ThreadID=22;_ThreadName=Thr
ead-3;_TimeMillis=1658900980068;_LevelValue=800;|
  Employee|#]

[#|2022-07-27T07:49:40.068+0200|INFO|glassfish 4.0||_ThreadID=22;_ThreadName=Thr
ead-3;_TimeMillis=1658900980068;_LevelValue=800;|
  ****Account amount status****true*****Account status**true--Results--OK-AC-AMT
|#]

[#|2022-07-27T07:49:40.068+0200|INFO|glassfish 4.0||_ThreadID=22;_ThreadName=Thr
ead-3;_TimeMillis=1658900980068;_LevelValue=800;|
  *******setDataReq***********|#]

[#|2022-07-27T07:49:40.068+0200|INFO|glassfish 4.0||_ThreadID=22;_ThreadName=Thr
ead-3;_TimeMillis=1658900980068;_LevelValue=800;|
  *******TypeId***********1|#]

[#|2022-07-27T07:49:40.068+0200|INFO|glassfish 4.0||_ThreadID=22;_ThreadName=Thr
ead-3;_TimeMillis=1658900980068;_LevelValue=800;|
  *******WalletSyncId***********c95d29ff-de52-4b2b-8a3f-59771e4a7bc7|#]

[#|2022-07-27T07:49:40.068+0200|INFO|glassfish 4.0||_ThreadID=22;_ThreadName=Thr
ead-3;_TimeMillis=1658900980068;_LevelValue=800;|
  *******dataReqId***********com.hdb.wallet.HdbWalletDataReqId@9bbaa6c|#]

[#|2022-07-27T07:49:40.068+0200|INFO|glassfish 4.0||_ThreadID=22;_ThreadName=Thr
ead-3;_TimeMillis=1658900980068;_LevelValue=800;|
  *******RqUID***********05bd5a17-3ad9-401d-b11e-37b8167e8dca|#]

[#|2022-07-27T07:49:40.068+0200|INFO|glassfish 4.0||_ThreadID=22;_ThreadName=Thr
ead-3;_TimeMillis=1658900980068;_LevelValue=800;|
  *******transactionAmt***********50.0|#]

[#|2022-07-27T07:49:40.068+0200|INFO|glassfish 4.0||_ThreadID=22;_ThreadName=Thr
ead-3;_TimeMillis=1658900980068;_LevelValue=800;|
  *******decryptedAcc***********0050000015557|#]

[#|2022-07-27T07:49:40.068+0200|INFO|glassfish 4.0||_ThreadID=22;_ThreadName=Thr
ead-3;_TimeMillis=1658900980068;_LevelValue=800;|
  *******debitCur***********EGP|#]

[#|2022-07-27T07:49:40.068+0200|SEVERE|glassfish 4.0||_ThreadID=22;_ThreadName=T
hread-4;_TimeMillis=1658900980068;_LevelValue=1000;|
  org.hibernate.TransactionException: JDBC begins transaction failed:
        at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jdbc.JdbcTransaction.doBegi
n(JdbcTransaction.java:76)
        at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.spi.AbstractTransactionImpl.begin(Ab
stractTransactionImpl.java:162)
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.beginTransaction(SessionImpl.java:
1471)
        at com.fawryis.ebpp.NewWebServiceFromWSDL.saveTransaction(NewWebServiceF
romWSDL.java:455)
        at com.fawryis.ebpp.NewWebServiceFromWSDL.setDataReq(NewWebServiceFromWS
DL.java:436)
        at com.fawryis.ebpp.NewWebServiceFromWSDL.debitAddReq(NewWebServiceFromW
SDL.java:210)
        at com.fawryis.ebpp.NewWebServiceFromWSDL.process(NewWebServiceFromWSDL.
java:98)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor61.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAcces
sorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
        at org.glassfish.webservices.InstanceResolverImpl$1.invoke(InstanceResol
verImpl.java:143)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.server.InvokerTube$2.invoke(InvokerTube.java:149)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.server.sei.SEIInvokerTube.processRequest(SEIInvokerTub
e.java:88)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.__doRun(Fiber.java:1136)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber._doRun(Fiber.java:1050)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.doRun(Fiber.java:1019)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.runSync(Fiber.java:877)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.helper.AbstractTubeImpl.process(AbstractTubeI
mpl.java:136)
        at org.glassfish.webservices.MonitoringPipe.process(MonitoringPipe.java:
142)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.helper.PipeAdapter.processRequest(PipeAdapter
.java:119)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.__doRun(Fiber.java:1136)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber._doRun(Fiber.java:1050)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.doRun(Fiber.java:1019)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.runSync(Fiber.java:877)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.helper.AbstractTubeImpl.process(AbstractTubeI
mpl.java:136)
        at com.sun.enterprise.security.webservices.CommonServerSecurityPipe.proc
essRequest(CommonServerSecurityPipe.java:210)
        at com.sun.enterprise.security.webservices.CommonServerSecurityPipe.proc
ess(CommonServerSecurityPipe.java:142)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.helper.PipeAdapter.processRequest(PipeAdapter
.java:119)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.__doRun(Fiber.java:1136)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber._doRun(Fiber.java:1050)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.doRun(Fiber.java:1019)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.runSync(Fiber.java:877)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.server.WSEndpointImpl$2.process(WSEndpointImpl.java:42
0)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter$HttpToolkit.handle(HttpAdap
ter.java:687)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter.handle(HttpAdapter.java:266
)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.ServletAdapter.handle(ServletAd
apter.java:169)
        at org.glassfish.webservices.JAXWSServlet.doPost(JAXWSServlet.java:169)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java
:1682)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperV
alve.java:318)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextV
alve.java:160)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.j
ava:734)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.jav
a:673)
        at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.j
ava:174)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.j
ava:357)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.jav
a:260)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(Container
Mapper.java:188)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.
java:191)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.ja
va:168)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpSer
verFilter.java:189)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(Executor
Resolver.java:119)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(De
faultFilterChain.java:288)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart
(DefaultFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultF
ilterChain.java:136)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultF
ilterChain.java:114)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.jav
a:77)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNI
OTransport.java:838)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(Abstr
actIOStrategy.java:113)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerTh
readIOStrategy.java:115)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(Wo
rkerThreadIOStrategy.java:55)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadR
unnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:135)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(Abs
tractThreadPool.java:564)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(Abstra
ctThreadPool.java:544)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: Closed Connection
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.getAutoCommit(PhysicalConnectio
n.java:4337)
        at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jdbc.JdbcTransaction.doBegi
n(JdbcTransaction.java:68)
        ... 65 more|#]
```

Note: I looked into some questions posted here but I'm not sure If they're suitable for my case as they're using Spring.

Comment: looks like it gets dead connection from connection pool: hbn tries to disable autocommit before starting transaction and fails.

Comment: HI didn't try as I don't have the code but I had this reason in mind.. Thank you very much for your answer